# making a template priority queue with vectors

Tags: templates, vector, queue, priority-queue, lnk2019

The following is a program to implement a priority queue.  I am using vectors to create the queue.  For this program, I want to be able to add any type of data using a template.  All of the code compiles correctly until I try to test the code by adding to the main function.  Can anyone catch what is going wrong here? below i have also indicated the line of code that gives me the error(down at the bottom in main).  Without it, the program runs fine.

---

PQ.h:

```
#ifndef PQ_H    
#define PQ_H    
#include <vector>    
using namespace std;    

template <typename T> struct vec//allows template vectors
    {    
        std::vector<T> vec0;
        std::vector<T> vec1;    
        std::vector<T> vec2;
        std::vector<T> vec3;    
        std::vector<T> vec4;
        std::vector<T> vec5;    
        std::vector<T> vec6;
        std::vector<T> vec7;    
        std::vector<T> vec8;    
        std::vector<T> vec9;
    };    

template <class T>    
void add(T item, int r);//adds to template queue    
template<class T>    
void remove();//removes from highest priority vector    
template<class T>    
bool empty();//check empty    
template<class T>
bool empty(int r);//check if specific rank is empty
```

## endif

---

PQFunction.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "PQ.h"
using namespace std;


template <class T>
void add(T item, int r)
{
        if (r==0)
    {
        vec0.push_back(item);
}
    if (r==1)
    {
        vec1.push_back(item);
    }
    if (r==2)
    {
        vec2.push_back(item);
    }
    if (r==3)
    {
        vec3.push_back(item);
    }
    if (r==4)
{
        vec4.push_back(item);
    }
    if (r==5)
    {
        vec5.push_back(item);
    }
    if (r==6)
    {
        vec6.push_back(item);
    }
    if (r==7)
        {
        vec7.push_back(item);
        }
    if (r==8)
{
    vec8.push_back(item);
    }
    if (r==9)
    {
        vec9.push_back(item);
    }
    if (r > 9 || r < 0)
    {
    cout<<"Rank is invalid"<<endl;
    }
}
template <class T>
void remove()
{
    if (!empty())
{
        if (!empty(0))
    {
        vec0.erase(vec0.begin);
        }
        else if(!empty(1))
        {
            vec1.erase(vec1.begin());
        }
        else if(!empty(2))
        {
            vec2.erase(vec2.begin());
        }
    else if(!empty(3))
        {
        vec3.erase(vec3.begin());
        }
        else if(!empty(4))
        {
        vec4.erase(vec4.begin());
        }
    else if(!empty(5))
        {
            vec5.erase(vec5.begin());
        }
        else if(!empty(6))
    {
            vec6.erase(vec6.begin());
    }
        else if(!empty(7))
    {
            vec7.erase(vec7.begin());
    }
    else if(!empty(8))
        {
        vec8.erase(vec8.begin());
        }
        else if(!empty(9))
    {
            vec9.erase(vec9.begin());
    }
}
    else
{
        cout<<"Nothing to remove"<<endl;
}
}
    template <class T>
    bool empty()
    {
        if (
        vec0.empty()&&
        vec1.empty()&&
        vec2.empty()&&
        vec3.empty()&&
        vec4.empty()&&
        vec5.empty()&&
        vec6.empty()&&
        vec7.empty()&&
        vec8.empty()&&
        vec9.empty())
        return true;

}

    template <class T>
    bool empty(int r)
    {
        if (r == 0)
    {
        return vec0.empty();
}
if (r==1)
{
        return vec1.empty();
}
    if (r==2)
{
        return vec2.empty();
}
    if (r==3)
{
        return vec3.empty();
}
    if (r==4)
{
        return vec4.empty();
}
    if (r==5)
{
        return vec5.empty();
}
    if (r==6)
{
        return vec6.empty();
}
    if (r==7)
{
        return vec7.empty();
}
        if (r==8)
{
        return vec8.empty();
}
    if(r==9)
{
        return.vec9.empty();
}
```

}

---

PQueue.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "PQ.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
```

{

```
**add(1,0);//this single line of code gives me the lnk error but when removed, the program compiles fine**

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Well, you probably forgot to link the library that implements `add()`. How did you link the program? Try something like: `g++ PQueue.cpp PQFunction.cpp -o prog`.